# CellPreviewEvent GWT

Tags: events, gwt, celltable

I have used cellTable named as 'table' in UIbinder and wish to check which cell is clicked. I have learnt on google that CellPreviewEvent can be used for this purpose. I used following syntax to catch the event in my Java code. but it fails with error:
Field 'table' does not have an 'addCellPreviewEvent.Handler' method associated.
I would appreciate if anybody can help me :

```
@UiHandler("table")
void tableclickedAddClick(CellPreviewEvent<?> e) {
    Window.alert("tablickclicked");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@UiHandler` unfortunately relies on naming conventions to find the `addXxxHandler` methods, and because the handler is named `CellPreviewEvent.Handler` and not `CellPreviewHandler`, it won't find the `addCellPreviewHandler` (it looks for `addCellPreviewEvent.Handler`).

That means that, in this case, you cannot use `@UiHandler` and must call `addCellPreviewHandler` yourself.